# Trying to shift rows down to add spaces between dates in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
DateSort = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

 For currentDate = 2 To DateSort
    If Range("B" & currentDate) <> Range("B" & currentDate + 1) Then
        currentDate = currentDate + 1
        myRange = "A" & currentDate & ":" & "Q" & DateSort
        Range(myRange).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.Clear
        myNewRange = "A" & currentDate + 1
        Range(myRange).PasteSpecial
        Selection.PasteSpecial

   End If

 Next
```

I have dates in column "B" of my worksheet. I would like to put a blank row between each group of dates. (They are already sorted)

Currently, my code will check for a new date, select the rest of the dates, copy, and clear the data but will fail when it gets to pasting it into the new range.

Comment: If you are inserting rows then work from the bottom up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried modifying your logic to make it work, but even now there is an error because your code is not well written. If there are many different dates the last couple of dates will not have spacing.

```
datesort = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

 For currentDate = 2 To datesort
    If Range("B" & currentDate) <> Range("B" & currentDate + 1) Then
        currentDate = currentDate + 1
        myRange = "A" & currentDate & ":" & "Q" & datesort
        Range(myRange).Select
        Selection.Copy
        'Selection.Clear
        myNewRange = "A" & currentDate + 1
        Range(myNewRange).PasteSpecial
        Range("B" & currentDate).Clear
        'Selection.PasteSpecial
        datesort = datesort + 1
   End If

 Next
```

Here is another version of the code with major modification, but it works perfectly

```
datesort = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

 For currentdate = 2 To datesort * 2
    If Range("B" & currentdate) <> Range("B" & currentdate + 1) Then
        Range(Range("B" & currentdate + 1), Range("B" & currentdate + 1).End(xlDown)).Select

        If Selection.Cells.Count < 20000 Then
            currentdate = currentdate + 1
            Selection.Copy
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial
            Range("B" & currentdate).Clear
        End If

   End If

 Next
```

Comment: That works and there should never be more than 3 different dates. What would you suggest doing to make my code written nicer? I am modifying someone else's code so I'm trying to copy his style.